# Can we have many ObjectOutputStream running simultaneously just by using one socket in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

It's like

```
Socket sk = new Socket(ip,port);
ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutStream(sk.getOutputStream());
....same for out2
 ObjectInputStream in1 = new ObjectInputStream(sk.getInputStream());
....:same for in2
new Thread(new Thread1(out1,in1)).start();
new Thread(new Thread2(out2,in2)).start();
```

can we have something like this-to read and write 2 different kinds of data simultaneously? In my case, it is transferring files while sending message?

Comment: If there are many rivers running in the same bed: will their waters mingle or stay apart?

Comment: XY problem. I suggest you state your actual objective. You don't need multiple ObjectOutputStreams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.. unless.. you write a threadsafe stream multiplexer. (like https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/jcsp/jcsp-1.1-rc4/jcsp-doc/org/jcsp/plugNplay/Multiplex.html but doesn't look threadsafe)

Imagine those streams on the other side of the socket. How do you know which bits come from which thread if everything is transferred over a single channel?